Escape '##' in Mako templates and not have it interpreted like a comment
I have this file
## Hello

% for i in range(2):
 ${i}
% endfor

When I run mako-render I get:
0
1

But I want:
## Hello

0
1

But I don't know how to escape ## and have Mako not interpret it as a comment. Is it possible?

According to a previous mailing list post, there’s no way to escape line comments.
You can use a <%text> block:
<%text>
## Hello
</%text>

or an expression substitution:
${"##"} Hello

